# Background Color of listview in percentage

Tags: android, listview, colors, background

Is it possible to color the background of a Listview element with a percentage factor? For example, if I have 3 elements in the Listview and one of them has 2 points and another one has only one:

A:2 points---->66.6666666%

B:1 point---->33.3333333%

C:0 point---->0%

Can I color the background in some way, like this?

A|--------------        |

B|------                |

C|                      |

Comment: For this , use custom Listview.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/voteBackground"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray_light"

            >

         </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVote"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVoteNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="dsadsadsadsadsa"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and after I change the width of the frameLayout from the adapter with setLayoutParams

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources()
        .getDisplayMetrics();
int  screenWidthInPix=displayMetrics.widthPixels;
FrameLayout background = (FrameLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.voteBackground);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = background.getLayoutParams();
params.width = (screenWidthInPix*entry.getVote())/total;
background.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [`ClipDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip) and setting the level of the drawable inside of `getView()` in your list adapter.